Elokai Neshama and Hamaavir Sheina Shavuot morning
When staying up all night, as some do on Shavuot, not all Birkot Hashachar can be said.
The following berachot can be more easily be dealt with without being yotze from someone else.

Al netilat yadayim and Asher Yatzar, based on the mishna berura after alos one goes to the bathroom and can then recite both berachot after washing hands.
Birkat Hatorah, assuming that one slept the day before and relies on the ruling of Rabbi Akiva Eiger that one can then say birkat Hatora the next day.
All of birkot Hashachar (except for Hamaavir sheina) are unrelated to sleeping the night before so they can be said (per shulchan aruch 46/8).

What about Elokai Neshama and Hamaavir Sheina. The Mishna Berura (46/24) brings two opinions,  one is to say it, the other , not to.
Are there any contemporary poskim who rule on this?

Don't forget hamapil, which has the same sort of issue

See https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5772-shavuos/
Birchos Ha-Shachar On Shavuos Morning by Rabbi Doniel Neustadt which includes this paragraph:
Elokai neshamah and ha-Ma’avir sheinah—Here, too, there are differences of opinion among the poskim as to whether one who remains awake throughout the night may recite these blessings. Mishnah Berurah[16] rules that it is best to hear these blessings from another person who slept. If no such person is available, many poskim rule that these blessings may be recited even by one who did not sleep[fn17].
[fn17 citing] Shulchan Aruch ha-Rav 46:7; Kaf ha-Chayim 46:49; Aruch ha-Shulchan 46:13; Misgeres ha-Shulchan 7:2.
Psak of Dayan Zobin of Ner Yisrael, London for 5784:
“Elokai Neshama & HaMa'avir Shaina: Ideally you should hear these from someone who slept. If that is not possible you can make these Berachot yourself”
https://images.shulcloud.com/945/uploads/ShavuotHalachot2024.pdf

If you like my answer, please consider accepting it. Otherwise, please comment on how it can be improved.
